# Changing a capital letter (read from cin) to lower case?

Tags: c++, string

> i wanna change the capital cin to lower case for the input , for example if cin>> one 
>   one=R it should be r so it convert it automatically

```
    #include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string one;
    string two;
cout << "\nPlayer One, please enter your move: ('p'  for Paper, 'r' for Rock, '$
cin >> one;

cout <<"\nPlayer Two, please enter your move: ('P' for Paper, 'R' for Rock, 'S'$
cin >> two;
```

Comment: There may be something that can change a character from upper [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) case.

Comment: yes there is but i dont have the right code. My thought was like this one= tolower (one); but it didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" is a *poor* way to describe a problem to other developers.

Comment: `std::transform(one.begin(), one.end(), one.begin(), ::tolower);`, and don't try it on a string with extended ascii.

Comment: what i should do with string

Comment: âtransformâ is not a member of âstdâ

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code using transform:

```
string one;
string two;
cout << "\nPlayer One, please enter your move: ('p'  for Paper, 'r' for Rock, '" << std::endl;
cin >> one;

std::transform(one.begin(), one.end(), one.begin(), ::tolower);
cout <<"\nPlayer Two, please enter your move: ('P' for Paper, 'R' for Rock, 'S'" << std::endl;
cin >> two;
std::transform(two.begin(), two.end(), two.begin(), ::tolower);
std::cout << "one=" << one << " ; two=" << two << std::endl;
```

The output may be as follows (for R, P):

```
Player One, please enter your move: ('p'  for Paper, 'r' for Rock, '
R

Player Two, please enter your move: ('P' for Paper, 'R' for Rock, 'S'
P
one=r ; two=p
```

Comment: @user3378134 include the header <algorithm>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <ctype>

tolower(char)
```

For a string input, you'll have to convert character by character:

```
char str[]="ONE TWO\n";
char c;
int i=0;
while (str[i])
{
  c=str[i];
  str[i] = (char) tolower(c);  //I think it return an int, which you need to typecast to a char
  i++;
}
```

Comment: do u mean like this for exemple    one#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
        string one;
        string  two;

cout << "\nPlayer One, please enter your move: ('p'  for Paper, 'r' for Rock, 's' for Scissor)\n";
cin >> one;

cout <<"\nPlayer Two, please enter your move: ('P' for Paper, 'R' for Rock, 'S' for Scissor)\n";
cin >> two;
one= tolower (string);

Comment: Check my updated ans for a `string`, also it returns an `int` which you need to typecast to a `char`

Answer (score 0):

the transform is the right way to do it, i think, you just need to include the algorithm library

```
#include <ctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::transform(one.begin(), one.end(), one.begin(), ::tolower); 
std::transform(two.begin(), two.end(), two.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: cannot convert âstd::stringâ to âintâ for argument â1â to âi                                 nt tolower(int)â

Comment: This because it returns an int, you need to typecast it to char*.

Comment: you were right.  see revised answer, I've tried it out, and it works on my system

Answer (score 0):

In header file " ctype.h" 
there are functions which supports case formatting

such as : tolower(var) formats text to lower case, 
          toupper(var) formats text to upper case

Comment: I didn't get ur idea i am sorry can u explain more

Comment: for example lets take your case your first input is from user comes in "one" so we use tolower function to convert this input to lower case `cin>>one; one = tolower(one);` this will convert it

Answer (score 0):

You should store your character in variable and change the variable

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char one{};
    char two{};
cout << "\nPlayer One, please enter your move: ('p'  for Paper, 'r' for Rock, '$
cin >> one;
one = tolower(one);

cout <<"\nPlayer Two, please enter your move: ('P' for Paper, 'R' for Rock, 'S'$
cin >> two;
one = tolower(two);
```